# PDO: Length of database name is too long

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

So I have a weird problem. With PHP I run through databases and I do some queries with PDO on each database. Everything works great but when the length of the database name is greater than 27, I have an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] 
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server. 
(severity 5)
```

I don't know if it's just a coincidence but with 90 databases, I have this problem just for those who have a greater than 27.

Do you have an idea of the problem and how to solve it? I haven't find a thing about issues like that.

```
class BD_TEST {
…

private function __construct(){}
private function __clone(){}
private function __destruct(){
    self::$oDB_main = null;
    self::$oDB_error = null;
}

public static function getInstance() {
    …


    if (!self::$oDB_main) {
        try {
            //Error in the next line
            self::$oDB_main = new PDO("mssql:host=".$prj_server.",".$prj_port.";dbname=[".$prj_datasource."]",$prj_user,$prj_pass);
            self::$oDB_main->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch (Exception $e) {echo($e."<br>Impossible to connect to [".$prj_datasource."] on ".$prj_server.":".$prj_port." with the user ".$prj_user."\n\n ".$e->getMessage());exit(0);}
    }
    return self::$oDB_main;


}

...
```

}

Comment: New SQL Server database name is stored as `SYSNAME` data type that is same as `nvarchar(128)` therefore you should be able to have database names up to `128` characters. Older database it used to be `varchar(30)`

Comment: What's the name of your db? maybe it has a character that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Nope, i checked the character are all good
Ex: amstedindustrie_60_amstedindustrie_sp_dev

Comment: But it's not that because i'm using sql server 2008

Comment: Mysterious.  Maybe you should post a few lines of the code that gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's no actual problem:

```
Messages with a severity level of 0 to 10 are informational messages and not actual errors.
```

Source: 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/25/sql-server-error-messages-sysmessages-error-severity-level/

If you decide the situation is all right, you may need to suppress the error message, perhaps by turning off error-reporting.

---

**UPDATE:**  You say your program is crashing and the error message is not meaningful.

1. Set error_reporting high and see if PHP coughs up something better.
2. Check the log files for PHP, Server, and SQL Server

Comment: But the situation is not all right. And even with error_reporting(0); my program crash with there DB.